# how to change the format of specific text that has been out put in a mysql while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, formatting

My database:

```
 --------------------------------------------
|   id  |  col1  |  col12  |  col3  |  col4  |
 --------------------------------------------
|   id  |  item1 |  40000  |  $400  |    1   |
|   id  |  item1 |  60000  |  $300  |    0   |
|   id  |  item1 |  80000  |  $200  |    0   |
|   id  |  item1 |  10000  |  $800  |    1   |
 --------------------------------------------
```

My query:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id"; 
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
$var = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];   
    $var1 = $row['col1'];
    $var2 = $row['col2'];
    $var3 = $row['col3'];
    $var3 = $row['col4'];

    $var .= "<div id='div1'><img src='$var1'/></div>
  <div id='div2'>$var2</div>
  <div id='div3'>$var3</div>
  <div id='div4'>$var4</div>";

}
```

How I want it to output the data is the items that have a "1" in col3 should be bold and possibly a different colour and the other text remains whatever the page font/text is set out as.

As below

```
---------------------------------------------------
|   id      |    col1    |    col12    |    col3  |
---------------------------------------------------
|   id      |    item1   |    40000    |    $400  |
|   id      |    item1   |    60000    |    $300  |
|   id      |    item1   |    80000    |    $200  |
|   id      |    item1   |    10000    |    $800  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible within a while loop? If not then how else could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id"; 
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
$var = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];   
    $var1 = $row['col1'];
    $var2 = $row['col2'];
    $var3 = $row['col3'];
    $var4 = $row['col4'];
if($var4==1) { $style = "font-weight:bold"; } 
    $var .= "<div id='div1'><img src='$var1'/></div>
  <div style="$style" id='div2'>$var2</div>
  <div style="$style" id='div3'>$var3</div>
  <div style="$style" id='div4'>$var4</div>";

}
```

Comment: I worded this question so that it would be as open and helpful to others - but using your code in my project is giving me a problem.

In the output 1-5 are normal font weight then 6 should be bold and 7 should be normal - but what it is doing changing the font-weight of everything after 5 all the way down making the rest of the results bold.

Comment: I worked it out and made the relevant changes to your code once the changes have been accepted I will make this the right answer.

Comment: You have to create css classes and map each class to the field from your DB.

Comment: yes that is all done but your code didn't do what I wanted it to.

When I added 
if($var4==0) { $style = "font-weight:normal"; }

it worked perfectly.

Plus I had to declare the $style variable otherwise it was returning an undefined index error.

Comment: @AasimAzam Rather than edit this answer I suggest you to post the code that works for you in the the separate answer.

Comment: Idolon +1 for great suggestion :)